# Restrict image movement to grid

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm trying to make the boxes move only in horizontal and vertical lines following the touchesMoved event.

I could easily check on every touch event if the center of the box is in the center of the current grid block and then allow a direction change. But that will require the touches to be very precise, and could also lead to bugs because of speedy fingers etc. and then miss the touch event.

What I essential would like to do is make the box move correctly in the grid, even though your touch path is not "perfect". See image below, blue lines indicates box movement, green line is the path of the touch. The box needs to follow the grid closest to the touch path, so it looks like your moving it.

How can i accomplish this?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the movement of the box should be smooth, not jump from grid to grid.

[image]

[Video](http://tinypic.com/r/bdmgwi/5)

Bonus info: I will also need to flicks boxes left/right up/down with touch momentum, and of course have some sort of collision detection, so boxes can't move through other boxes on the grid. Am I better off with a 2d physics engine?

Comment: A physics engine seem like overkill to me. All you need to know is if that coordinate is occupied.

Comment: I also think that a physics engine is overkill. I can easily check if a coordinate is occupied - how does that help with animating the movement of the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smooth animation based on hacker2007 answer:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:gridContainerView];
   for (UIView *subView in gridContainerView.subviews) {
      if (conditionForBeingAGridBlock && CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, touchPoint))       
      {
          [UIView beginAnimations:@"Dragging A DraggableView" context:nil];
          self.frame = CGRectMake(0, location.y, subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height);
          [UIView commitAnimations];
      }
   }
}
```

This will move the view you are dragging under your finger, you can add checks yourself to make sure that it doesn't go where it can't. But this will get your a smooth dragging animation.

---

Seems the problem is what you're setting the frame to in your anitamion:
Currently every time you move the square a little bit you get a new rect here:

```
CGRect rect = [self.grid getCellRect:self.grid.gridView x:cell.x y:cell.y];
```

Then in your animation you do this:

```
self.frame = rect;
```

Then you animate the box to that rect. So if you move your finger really quickly then you will get that 'skip' effect. If you change it to this:

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(location.x - self.bounds.size.width / 2, location.y - self.bounds.size.height / 2, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: This method gives a laggy experience if you move through the grid quickly, minor problem. The real problem is that it's still possible to move diagonally.

Comment: I added a [video link](http://tinypic.com/r/bdmgwi/5) to the question. I cannot figure out how to make a fluid animation that goes around a grid corner.

Comment: Oh I see what you are tring to do now. OK I've edited my answer.

Comment: Still not working, begin to doubt that it will work just with touchesMoved. I have an idea that I need to write a timer loop where I check for collisions.  I'm moving more towards the physics engine.

Comment: Why does it not work ? What's it doing that you don't want it to ?

Comment: Please check this demo project I just created http://goo.gl/U7zAVH - I want it to follow the touch, but only in X or Y axis. Also I can't figure out how to block "boxes" so that they can't move through other boxes. I think this is beyond the scope of this question, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: And the movement of the box should be fluid, eg. not jump from cell to cell.

Comment: Also see this: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007315

May provide some insight .

Comment: I already seen that. The problem is more the logic for making sure the boxes only move in straight lines, either horizontal or vertical, and they should only be able to change direction when they are aligned with the grid.

Comment: What iOS are you targetting ?? iOS 7 has some new spritekit and uidynamics stuff that's worth looking into. With adoption rates for iOS 7 suppose to be very high very quickly it is a viable option VS some more heavy duty cocosd2d type solution.

Comment: I was actually going to target iOS 6, but the adoption rates as you mentioned is really high, if the numbers are true. Keeping iOS 6 support would probably be best, but I'm not ruling out iOS 7 as target. Will try to make some tests with the new Dynamics

Comment: Looks like iOS 7 already has more users. This will only increase: 

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/09/23/ios-7-use-overtakes-ios-6-in-just-72-hours-apple-says-200-milli/

Won't be 100% accurate, but gives an indication.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach assuming your grid blocks are located in gridContainerView

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: gridContainerView];
      for (UIView *subView in gridContainerView.subviews) {
         if (conditionForBeingAGridBlock && 
               CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, touchPoint)) {
            box.frame = subview.frame;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the movement of the box, should be smooth, not jump from grid to grid.

Comment: If you want it to be smooth, set the new frame in an animation block: (see my answer below)